# Javascript file not update (first time)

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, caching, browser-cache

I am working on java web application. In my application some user defined javascript using.

When i update my javascript file and run my project in browsers, so first time not get updated javascript file and when i refresh (ctrl+F5) page after get updated javascript file.

so why first time i don't get updated javascript file?

Please guide me.

Comment: U can change the js file name when u update or clean the browsers before run. As you can't clean user browsers so better to change the file name.

It mostly happen due to form and cookies data

Comment: Yes, i tried this option as well. What happends is initially it works well but somehow after few days we face same issue with that file as well

Comment: Not really a programming question. On intial page load you get a version of the js file that the browser cached earlier and CTRL+F5 is a commonly used keyboard shortcut in browsers to forse a complete refresh of all resources (where only pressing F5 would be a "normal" refresh).

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the cache headers that your server is sending. Specifically, you need to lower the expiration date that clients are likely to use for things like Javascript files.

Otherwise, the client is going to cache them -- just like they are supposed to do.